# dynamic WPS call and render as WMS with geoserver layers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoserver, wms, wps

I have a hard time figuring out if it is possible for a user to generate on the fly (via a javascript/openlayers app) a WPS request to geoserver and that the output is rendered as a WMS image?
So lets say the user selects 2 raster layers, a WPS request is POSTed to perform a specific transformation of the data, and then the output of this transformation is  rendered back to the user's app via a WMS image.
Thanks for your help,  I have a hard time finding any info on that regard!

Comment: That's no problem, what's not working for you? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, in fact, I read a post that was basically what I wanted to do and that you have already answered, but only was working partially ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387677/displayer-raster-result-from-geoserver-wps-in-openlayers4 ). Following the link you shared (https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/wps/chaining_processes.html), it seems possible to build a WPS request and use the gs:Import process to create a layer (which then can be fetch with a WMS request), but it seems that the inputs feeding this gc:import are "static".

Comment: Is there a way to use this gc:import process to genererate on the fly a in-memory layer that will be used by the webapp user? Otherwise, since the original post you answered before is quite old, do you know if there is now a way to use WPS geotiff response within a fetch request as a openlayers raster layer?